# Flot Grid with Customised Borders

Tags: javascript, flot

Flot enables us customise grid borders. This is documented [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid) with the following:

```
grid: {
    borderWidth: number or object with "top", "right", "bottom" and "left" properties with different widths
    borderColor: color or null or object with "top", "right", "bottom" and "left" properties with different colors
}
```

However, I couldn't manage to come up with a successfully working example. To create a custom grid with top and left border with white color I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
grid: {
    borderWidth: {top: 1, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 1},
    borderColor: {top: "#FFF", left: "#FFF"}
}
```

Can anyone provide a working example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which version of flot are you using? The borderWidth property did not accommodate an object as the value until version 0.8. Make sure you are using the latest version (0.8.1) and give it another shot. The only other thing I notice is the missing comma after the borderWidth values. Should be "left: 1 }**,** borderColor..."

Comment: I am using v0.8.1. I mistakenly forgot the comma while putting code here. Still it does not work.