# Flot chart - change border color

Tags: javascript, flot

It is possible to change border color in flot.js chart? I didn't find answer. [image]

Comment: where can i find `plot.js` library?

Comment: @luchosrock sorry by mistake i write plot instead of flot

Comment: Without code, this question may be off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working the way I want?**") must include: A) the desired behavior; B) a specific problem or error *and* C) **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** all ***in the question itself***. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using to initialize the plot? Then the answer could modify your code to correctly set the border color.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flot Grid with Customised Borders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570992/flot-grid-with-customised-borders)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the documentation here, it contains the answer you're looking for: https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid

You can set the border of a plot like this:

```
$.plot("#placeholder", [ data ], {
  grid: { 
    borderColor: "#FFF"
  }
});
```

You can control the individual borders for top, left, bottom, right if you use `{top: "#FFF", bottom:"#222", ...}` etc., instead of just `"#FFF"`. Additionally you can set the width of the borders with the `borderWidth` property.

See this jsfiddle, all the way at the bottom of the script, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/2pnJE/15/

Comment: ty for answer my question